# How do you make an application not run with elevated priviledges

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, uac

I have this problem that started recently(about 3 days ago), every time I run `Vim` or `Scite` either by clicking
its icon or using the context menu, it brings up the `UAC` dialog asking me if I want to run it with elevated priviledges. The thing is, I haven't set it to run as administrator. I have no problem with it running with elevated priviledges, the problem is having to click yes every time I open a file. I don't want to change `UAC` settings to "Don't prompt me". I want `Vim` to run the usual way.

**Additional details:**
Their icons have the "shield" on the left bottom corner(obviously)
Vim and Scite both have an entry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Open with VIM` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Open with Scite` which I added myself. However, there's also an entry for `JEdit` there yet it runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I had to go to the location of the executable, right click on it and go to the compatibility tab. I then clicked `Change setting for all users` and disabled 'Run as administrator`(it's not the same as the one in the advanced option. Also, unset any compatibility options and it should work.